# When and who to detach observers when the observer has longer life span than the observable

Tags: c++, observer-pattern, observable

I encountered this problem using a third party library provided by a different group in the company (written in C++).

In the destructor of Observer, it detaches itself from all observables it subscribes to, this part makes sense to me. But in the destructor of Observable, it checks if the observable has any observer that's still in it's subscriber list. If so, throws an error.

I am going to put the fact that it intentionally throws an error in the destructor aside. Can someone try to explain to me the why the observable should expect no observers to outlive itself or is this just a bad design. If this is a bad design, when we are in circumstances when the observer outlives the observable, are there good ways to handle it?

Comment: I'm just wondering why observable would have shorter life than the observer (assuming that the observer is truly an observer, meaning that it *needs* to observe the observable as long as it exists).

Comment: I don't have a good answer to that. One observation I have is this library uses a mix of smart pointers (boost::shared_ptr) and raw pointers. And this particular problem shows up during shut down. It could be that because of the order things are done some other objects still hold a shared_ptr of the observer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the Observer has a pointer (or reference) to the Observable, and the Observable is destroyed, that pointer will be invalid.  The author is just trying to avoid dangling references.

There are three usual solutions, I think.

One is to do exactly what this code does, perhaps calling abort() rather than throwing an exception in the destructor.

Another is to have the Observable's destructor de-register itself from any Observers.

The last is to use "smart pointers" (e.g., a reference-counted `shared_ptr`) to guarantee that the Observable outlives any Observer.

Comment: Thanks Nemo. As you said, the observer class does hold pointers to all the observables it subscribes to. I guess under such design, we are implicitly assuming the observer does not outlive the observable.

Comment: I think the `deregister` approach is the most sensible. Then the Observer can react appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.  I would expect a totally generic
implementation of the observer pattern to support deleting an observed
object, at least optionally, but there are a lot of uses where this
doesn't make sense, and is probably a programming error.  In general,
before the observable fully destructs, it should notify its observers of
the fact that it will destruct; they should then unenrol.  Which means
that by the time the destructor of the observable registry object is
called, there should be no registered observers.

Answer (score 0):

I usually implemented the pattern the other way around- the Observable adds itself and takes itself away from the Observer's list. My Observer lives throughout the whole lifetime of the application, and the Observables live a few seconds, typically.

Comment: If you implement that way, then how would the observable know it's potential observers?

Comment: @DeadMG: Is your observable implemented on top of some frameworks? (See the Wikipedia articles on the differences between Observer pattern and Publish-subscribe pattern.)

Answer (score -1):

It's just bad design, nothing guarantees that the observable will outlive all of its observers.

If you have access to the observable's destructor, rewrite it so it will detach all of its observers remaining.